# Sort IP Address AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, sorting, filter, html-table, ng-filter

I have a table header IP Address, that use AngularJS to sort it. 
Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to sort IP address.

```
<th class="text-left">
    <a href="" ng-click="sortType = 'device.ip_address'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
        IP Address
    </a>
</th>
```

[image]

I want to use something like this

```
sortFn: function (a, b) {
    if (a == b) return 0;
    if ( +a.replace(/\./g, '') < +b.replace(/\./g, '')) return - 1;
    return 1;
}
```

How do I use this function above as my sort function in AngularJS?

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with what you have?

Comment: It does not seem to sort it. Since it treats it as a string.

Comment: Create custom filter: `.filter('myFilter', function() { return function(ips, reverse) { var temp = ips.sort(sortFn); return reverse ? temp.reverse() : temp; }})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *normalize* IPs (for example, from `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.001.001`) to properly compare them:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.ips = [
    "192.168.1.1",
    "192.168.2.3",
    "192.168.1.00",
    "192.168.1.3"
  ]
  $scope.sortIps = function(ip) {    
    return ip.split('.').map(function(x) {
      return x.padStart(3, "0");
    }).join('');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <a ng-init='sortReverse=false' href="" ng-click="sortReverse = !sortReverse">
      IP Address
  </a>  
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='ip in ips | orderBy : sortIps : sortReverse'>{{ip}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ng-repeat to display rows of your table you don't have to create your custom function just convert the Ip address to number

```
$scope.sortIp = function(ip){
    return parseInt(ip.split('.').join(""));
};
```

and let orderBy filter of angularjs do the job for you.

```
<button ng-click="order = !order">Order</button>
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:sortIp:order ">
    {{item}}
</div>
```

also orderBy takes a second parameter (true / false) for asc / desc ordering

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/8nb5VmGnb3QmQbzxeiFE?p=preview)**

Comment: I got mine map to ng-click, can you please kindly add your suggestion another version that align with ng-click ?

Comment: I also got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

Comment: Right now, I have this `<a href="" ng-click="sortIp(ip_address);sortReverse = !sortReverse">`

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or plunker of your code please, that way we can figure it much faster

Comment: @ihue, you should compare ips by sections, not via simple concatentaion. At case of `[ "192.168.1.00", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3","192.168.1.1"]` - `"192.168.1.00"` will be the greates.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function to sort IP addresses

```
const convertToNumber = (address) => {
    if (address === null || address === undefined) return null;
    if (address.indexOf(".") < 0) return address.padEnd(12, "0");

    return parseInt((address.split(".")
        .map(item => item.padEnd(3, "0"))
        .join("").padEnd(12,"0")));
};
```

For above IP addresses, you shall have
ips = [
"192.168.1.1",
"192.168.2.3",
"192.168.1.00",
"192.168.1.3"
].map(item=>console.log(convertToNumber(item)));

192168100100
192168200300
192168100000
192168100300,

The same approach can be applied to sort document sections (1.1, 1.1.1, 2.1.2 etc)